# How does Google Drive know what Apps I have installed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-drive-api

I was just browsing through my Google Drive, tried to open a .json file and it popped up a dialog asking me if I'd like to open the file using an app on my computer:

[image]

What API are they using to access this information?

Comment: Are you using chrome? If so then it's self explanatory. Chrome sold you out to Google :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the "Apps on your computer" section only appears if you have installed Google Drive on your computer. The "Suggested third-party apps" is just an XHR to an API, which retrieves a list of supported 3rd party apps, filtered by the extension type of the file you are viewing.

The way it works is through [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) between an app installed on the computer and a [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) installed within Chrome. Google Drive is an extension that is already built into Chrome. It is not something you installed yourself in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-drive/apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf) - it was pre-installed.

The Google Drive app installed on your computer is sending messages back and forth with the extension, and you can see these messages arriving in Chrome in the `extensions::messaging` script, which is run for all apps you load in the browser.

[image: extensions::messaging]

If you look at the following breakpoint, you can see I have found the message that was sent from the Google Drive app on my laptop to the built-in extension. It shows an array of five apps that could open the file I clicked on in the Google Drive web app.

[image: Native Messaging]